# Identifying the identical elements in two arrays with same location(index)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

Ok, so I want to return the elements that are present in both provided arrays having the same index location.

```
exe1 = [A,B,C,D,N]
exe2 = [B,D,C,A,T]
```

it should return only C

I've tried looping them by nested loops but doesn't work, here is what I've tried:

```
 let testing = []
       for (let i = 0; i < exe1.length; i++){
         for(let j = 0; j < exe2.length; j++){
           if(exe1[i] === exe2[j]){
             testing.push(exe1[i])
           }
         }
       };
       return testing;
```

mind the names of the arrays, please

Comment: Why do you have _two_ loops if you only need to compare at _one_ index at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [*filter*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiyl9js38_7AhU94HMBHb_vDlwQFnoECBMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AOvVaw3uj9Eml6lq1L49hIcVb04R) to only include values in `exe1` that have the same value at the same index of `exe2`.

```js
const exe1 = ['A','B','C','D','N'];
const exe2 = ['B','D','C','A','T'];

const testing = exe1.filter((val, i) => val === exe2[i]);

console.log(testing)
```

Comment: I've tried the filter for comparing arrays with more elements, let's say 15 elements each and it's not accurate, it works but not accurate, It misses some elements that are true to the condition we have in the function.

Comment: I find that hard to believe without some examples. Please edit your question with some sample data and make sure it's actually valid JS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a function that can do this and the datatypes are primitives you can do something like this. Just a loop that goes through each index, checks both arrays, and returns the value that is the same.

```js
const exe1 = ["A","B","C","D","N"];
const exe2 = ["B","D","C","A","T"];

function getElementsThatAreTheSame(arr1, arr2) {
  const minLength = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length);
  const sameArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    const item1 = arr1[i];
    const item2 = arr2[i];
    if (item1 == item2) sameArray.push(item1);
  }
  return sameArray;
}

const sameItems = getElementsThatAreTheSame(exe1, exe2);
console.log(sameItems)
```

However you could also use the filter method to accomplish this pretty easily as follows:

```js
const exe1 = ["A","B","C","D","N"];
const exe2 = ["B","D","C","A","T"];
const sameArr = exe1.filter((e, i) => exe2[i] == e);
console.log(sameArr);
```

the filter method will take a function as an argument to which is passed the element in the array and the index of that element. We can just check the second array at that index and make sure it is the same element.

Both these approaches will not verify if it is two objects which have the same content, but are different objects. i.e. `{foo: "bar"} !== {foo: "bar"}`